# Waiting for response from ObjectForScripting c# WebBrowser

Tags: c#, scripting, webbrowser-control

I would like to know how to wait until browser.document.InvokeScript(DoAll); returns.   as soon as it returns i need to start a different function, but ONLY once it has finished. how do i wait until a javascript function has finished before starting another?

```
public void DoAll() { 
// check for window type
   MainInst.BrowserForAutomation.Document.InvokeScript(JSFuncNames.CheckWindow);
       //Wait Until the command above has finished, before loading the command after this
// do a check to make sure the ticket is editable

// do a check to assign the ticket to the specified person
}
```

Comment: `InvokeScript` returns as soon as the JavaScript function it calls returns - not before - because JavaScript is single-threaded. Now if the JavaScript function uses timer or XHR to do something asynchronously, there should be a completion event you would want to handle.

Comment: @Noseratio , If in javascript i call a function called DOsomething() , which calls DoSomethingElse(), and like 2 other functions are chained together,   Will InvokeScript wait until it reaches a "return" keyword?

Comment: Yes. JavaScript is no different from other languages in this behavior.